# Example of 2 sets of different PDFs on $(X,Y)$ which produce the same PDF on $Z = g(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am wondering if anyone has concrete analytic examples of 2 different joint pdfs on random variables $X,Y$ which produce the same pdf on $Z$ where $Z$ is defined as $Z = g(X,Y)$. It is easy to come up with such an example for $g$ being linear as the example below. However, does anyone have an example in the case where $g$ is non-linear?

Example for the linear case: Consider $Z = X+Y$ where $X,Y$ are Gaussian random variables. If $Z \sim N(0,1)$, we can choose $X,Y \sim N(0, \frac{1}{2}), iid$. Or, we can also choose $X,Y$ to be Gaussian but correlated such that $\text{var}(Z) = \text{var}(X) + \text{var}(Y) + 2\text{cov}(X,Y) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You want any example with any non-linear function $g(x,y)$? There is too much freedom of choice.

Let $g(x,y)=x/y$.

Let $X, Y$ are independent standard normal r.v.'s. Then the distribution of $Z=g(X,Y)=\frac{X}{Y}$ is Cauchy with pdf $$f_Z(z)=\frac1\pi \frac{1}{1+z^2}.$$

Let $X_1, Y_1$ are independent standard normal r.v.'s. Let $U$ has discrete distribution $P(U=1)=P(U=2)=1/2$ and does not depend on $X_1, Y_1$. Define
$$
X=UX_1, \quad Y=UX_2.
$$
The joint pdf of $X,Y$ looks as follows:
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{8\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{8}}
$$
wich differs from joint pdf of two independent standard normal random variables.

But $Z=\frac{X}{Y}=\frac{X_1}{Y_1}$ is distributed exactly the same way as in the previous example: according to the same Cauchy distribution.